# Congruent figures have equal areas. Why?

Tags: geometry, axioms

When we are first introduced to the idea of congruent polygons (generally triangles) in school, we often define congruent figures as "figures which have the same shape and size". However, today, congruence seems to be (generally) described formally by isometries. How can we prove that congruent figures have equal areas using the (modern) definition of congruence?
Also, I don't think that Euclid ever proves that if we "cut" a polygon into any number of parts, the sum of the areas of the parts is equal to the area of the original. I'm not sure whether it even would have mattered to Euclid, since I have heard that he did not distinguish between polygons and their areas, and the case for polygons would have been covered by "the whole is equal to the sum of the parts. Is it possible to prove this? Or do we take it as another axiom?

Comment: If you want to ask a question like this, you first have to give us your definition of "area".

Comment: What is the definition used in modern mathematics(geometry)?

Comment: [Lebesgue measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) is one way of defining area.

Comment: The further you go down this rabbit hole the worse things will get. There exist subsets of the plane which do not have a well defined Lebesgue measure (i.e. area). There also exist ways of cutting up a square (I think anyway... it works for spheres at least) into a finite number of pieces, moving the pieces around to form two squares each with the same area as the original square (assuming the axiom of choice).

Comment: @DanielRust Could you please give some more information, particularly about your two squares and AC?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox

Comment: @Daniel: That doesn't work in two dimensions.

Comment: @TonyK ok, I should have been more careful. I believe you can at least cut a square up into a countably infinite number of pieces and rearrange them to get another square.

Comment: @ABajaj: Perhaps a better starting point is [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area#Formal_definition).

Comment: @Daniel: Do you mean another square of a different area? I do't think so.

Comment: @TonyK any interval is countably $\mathbb{R}$-equidecomposable to $\mathbb{R}$ and so in particular any two finite unions of intervals are countably $\mathbb{R}$-equidecomposable. See [Corollary 1](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/245b-notes-2-amenability-the-ping-pong-lemma-and-the-banach-tarski-paradox-optional/#more-1354) in these notes of Terry Tao.

Comment: If you accept that area is preserved under an isometry then you're just saying that if there exists an isometry taking one subset of the plane to another, then those subsets must also have the same area.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I'm sorry.You are right about countable equidecomposability.